# NullPointerException when running JUnit test with TestEntityManager in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit4

**Error Description:**
When running the test `findByEmail` in the `ClientRepositoryTest` class, a `NullPointerException` occurs with the message "Cannot invoke `org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persist(Object)` because `com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.ClientRepositoryTest.entityManager` is null."

**Code Snippet:**

```java
package com.saajf.manager.eewaapro;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;

import com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.domain.entities.Client;
import com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.infrastructure.repositories.ClientRepository;

@DataJpaTest
class ClientRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    private static TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    void findByEmail() {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setId(1L);
        client.setCompanyAddress1("cr 54 # 143a - 90");
        client.setCompanyName("cualquier cosa");
        client.setCompanyType("Software");
        client.setCompanyPhone1("3165476589");
        client.setEmail("test@example.com");
        client.setIdentification("123456789");

        // Guardar el cliente utilizando el entityManager persistente
        Client savedClient = entityManager.persist(client);

        // Limpiar el entityManager para asegurar que se recargue el cliente desde la
        // base de datos
        entityManager.clear();

        // Realizar la búsqueda del cliente por email
        Client foundClient = clientRepository.findByEmail(savedClient.getEmail());

        assertThat(foundClient).isEqualTo(savedClient);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Parent -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.atukaa.eewaapro.manager</groupId>
    <artifactId>eewaapro-manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eewaapro-manager</name>
    <description>Manager component for the Atukaa Eewaapro Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <!-- Add your dependencies here -->
    ...
    <!-- Build -->
    <!-- Add your build configuration here -->
    ...
</project>
```

**Stack Overflow Question:**
Title: NullPointerException when running JUnit test with TestEntityManager

I'm experiencing a `NullPointerException` when running a JUnit test with `TestEntityManager`. The error message states: "Cannot invoke `org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persist(Object)` because `com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.ClientRepositoryTest.entityManager` is null."

contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mTests [0;1mrun: [0;1m1[m, Failures: 0, [1;31mErrors: [0;1;31m1[m, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.892 s[1;31m <<< FAILURE![m - in com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.[1mClientRepositoryTest[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] findByEmail  Time elapsed: 0.239 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persist(Object)" because "com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.ClientRepositoryTest.entityManager" is null
at com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.ClientRepositoryTest.findByEmail(ClientRepositoryTest.java:33)

2023-05-15 23:24:32.471  INFO 13068 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Comment: 1. Remove `static`, 2. add `@Autowired`. 3. Read the documentation which explains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to autowire the `TestEntityManager` as follows:

```java
@DataJpaTest
class ClientRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: However, an error occurs:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.saajf.manager.eewaapro.domain.entities.Client
 aused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist